# Text passed in the search box is invisible in firefox- A/B testing

Tags: manual-testing

I am performing A/B testing using optimizely. Testing one of the variation in firefox.

Text typed is invisible in search box for the variation experiment. This is happening in Firefox only. No issues when i tested in chrome.

Are there any reasons this? Also how can i fix this issue?

Comment: has to be a compatibility issue, try different version of Firefox, see what happens

Comment: But the original site is working fine when passing text. The variation site is not showing up the text. For the same version.

Comment: It's defenetly compatibility issue. Also it depends how you make your A/B testing e.g. directly or locally through some proxy tools. Check the DevTools console in the Browser it might have any additional information about this issue something like a CORS error or others. There are no any additional information in your question to help you.